# Using bulk editor to list the active pages

Tags: aem

Hi I tried using bulk editor to get the list of Pages from a particular path

But it returned both activated and deactivated page. I need only the Activated pages 
I gave Custom Properties / Columns as cq:lastReplicationAction . This gave a column with values Activated & deactivated is there a way to get only activated pages alone in bulk editor

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://localhost:4502/etc/importers/bulkeditor.html?rootPath=/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en&queryParams=%22jcr:content/cq:lastReplicationAction%22:Activate%20type:Page&initialSearch=true

Refer to this doc:

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/administering/bulk_editor.html

Or read the source code in CRX/De for more details:

See source code here:

/libs/wcm/core/components/bulkeditor/bulkeditor.jsp

Tested in AEM 5.6.1. Should work in 6.X as well.

Cheers!